# Update of Azure Datalake house table that was built pointing to a container in a datalake

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure synapse and we are evaluating if we should use the tool for datawarehousing.
I am trying to understand the concept of tables in datalakehouse instance inside synapse. If a table is built that is pointing to a container in another Datalake. would it automatically get the new data when I run the query, if there is new data in the source location?.

Comment: Could you please clearly mention what is your source and destination. Also, please provide the information about what are you trying to do.

Comment: My Source is a folder with CSV files inside a Azure Gen 2 Datalake. My destination is an external table in a lakehouse database in Azure Synapse. I want to figure out if we create that external table, once created, would I need to do anything else to capture data updates or as the external table is pointing to the source, it would update automatically or run the script everytime we query it so that it captures new data.